# Breaking out of nested while True loop

Tags: python

I am running a `while True:` loop in a webscraping script. I want the scraper to run in an incremental loop until running into a certain error. The general question is about how to break out of a while True loop when a certain condition is matched. The code as is just keeps on outputting the first run forever:

```
output 1;1
...
output 1;n
```

This is a minimal reproducible example of my code.

```
runs = [1,2,3]

for r in runs:
    go = 0
    while True:
        go +=1
        output = ("output " + str(r) + ";" +str(go))
        try:
            print(output)
        except go > 3:
            break
```

The desired output is:

```
output 1;1
output 1;2
output 1;3
output 2;1
output 2;2
output 3;3
output 3;1
output 3;2
output 3;3
[done]
```

Comment: A simple way is to package this loop into a function / def / class-method and 'return'

Comment: Your `try` statement isn't going to work because you will always be able to print the output (even if go is greater than 3), because no error will be thrown. Instead, you probably want to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Your code does not work because the `except` statement must be followed by an `Exception` child object (or a tuple of those objects). If an exception is raised by the code inside the `try` block, the code inside the `except` block is executed. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `try` and `except` here. Keep things simple and just use a simple `while` condition on your `go` variable. In that case, you don't even need a `break` because as soon as `go>=3`, the condition will be `False`, you will come out of the while loop and restart the while loop for the next value of `r`.

```
runs = [1,2,3]

for r in runs:
    go = 0
    while go <3:
        go +=1
        output = ("output " + str(r) + ";" +str(go))
        print(output)
```

**Output**

```
output 1;1
output 1;2
output 1;3
output 2;1
output 2;2
output 2;3
output 3;1
output 3;2
output 3;3
```

**Alternative to while** : As suggested by @chepner, you don't even need `while` and are better off with a for loop over `go` as

```
for r in runs:
    for go in range(1, 4):
        output = ("output " + str(r) + ";" +str(go))
        print(output)
```

Comment: Further, since `go` is unconditionally incremented each time through the loop and there's no other exit condition, I'd just use another `for` loop (`for go in range(0, 3):`) instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: Good point. But I thought the user specifically wants to use while loop. Wait a minute and I will add your suggestion to my answer

Comment: @chepner: I added your suggestion in my answer. Although to get the desired output, I had to use `range(1, 4)`